# how do i get the last insert id of two different insert query. i have got the first one for the first query and i stored it in a variable

Tags: php, mysql

how do i get the last insert id of two different insert query. i have got the first one for the first query and i stored it in a variable how do i get the second insert last id and also store in a variable, for use.

here is my code:

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO `resume` (`uID`,`profSummary`,`status`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",
                       GetSQLValueString( test_input($row_user["uID"]), "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString( test_input($_POST["proSum"]), "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString( 1, "int"));

mysqli_select_db($dbmain, $database_dbmain);
$Result1 = mysqli_query($dbmain, $insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error($dbmain));
            $lastResume_id = $dbmain->insert_id;

$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO `education` (`eduType`,`from`,`to`,`degree`,`course`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
                       GetSQLValueString( test_input($value), "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString( test_input($from[$cnt]), "date"),
                       GetSQLValueString( test_input($to[$cnt]), "date"),
                       GetSQLValueString( test_input($_POST["level"][$cnt]), "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString( test_input($_POST["ctitle"][$cnt]), "text"));

mysqli_select_db($dbmain, $database_dbmain);
$Result1 = mysqli_query($dbmain, $insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error($dbmain));
                $edu_id = $dbmain->insert_id;
```

i tried this but its not working its still giving me the last insert id of the first insert query instead of the second query last insert id.

Comment: What's `GetSQLValueString` is it a custom made SQL injection protection function?

Comment: Are you sure it's incorrect? Perhaps the auto_increment values are currently the same for both tables. Also check to see if your education table has any triggers that might also be doing an INSERT.

Comment: What you've written should work.

Comment: Are you sure the `education` table has an auto-increment ID column?

Comment: You can check out this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: BTW, it's confusing to switch between procedural and OO syntax. I recommend you use OO syntax consistently, it's less verbose.

Comment: Thanks let me check my tables and try again